# jQuery improve show/hide script to include fadeToggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a script that I found somewhere online that shows or hides divs based on radio button clicks.

I am trying to improve this by adding either fadeToggle() or slideToggle() to the transition. However when I do this the function does not work like it used to.
It shows both divs and hides them both again when I click the other radio button.

```
// Show/Hide forms based on radio button selection
$('input[name="screen_type"]').bind('change',function(){
var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 2) ? true : false;
$('.welcome_screen').toggle(showOrHide);
    var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;
$('.training_screen').toggle(showOrHide);
});
```

Please see the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/JEbFq/

Thanks for all the help guys, cheers

Comment: "does not work like it used to". What did it used to work like, and what do you want it to work like?

Comment: I've updated the question with an explanation, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fadeToggle and slideToggle don't take the parameter to show or hide [api doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it instead: http://jsfiddle.net/hzSnU/1/

Comment: Thanks for answering that but any idea how to implement the same functionality using fadeToggle? Cheers

Comment: You're wrong: he's referring to toggle, and he's following the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/): "The second version of the method accepts a Boolean parameter. If this parameter is `true`, then the matched elements are shown..."

Answer (score 1):

Try this method: http://jsfiddle.net/JEbFq/20/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
// Hide lis
    $(".training_screen").hide();
    $(".welcome_screen").hide();    

// Show/Hide forms based on radio button selection
    $('input[name="screen_type"]').bind('change',function(){
        var fnTraining, fnWelcome;
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            fnTraining = "slideDown";
            fnWelcome = "slideUp";
        } else {
            fnTraining = "slideUp";
            fnWelcome = "slideDown";
        }
        $('.welcome_screen')[fnWelcome]();
        $('.training_screen')[fnTraining]();
 });​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4aSbG/

Or, you could make a slideToggleOption jQuery method that takes the show/hide parameter and use it like this:

```
// Hide lis
    $(".training_screen").hide();
    $(".welcome_screen").hide();    

jQuery.fn.slideToggleOption = function(show /* other optional args from slideToggle */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (show) {
        return(this.slideDown.apply(this, args));
    } else {
        return(this.slideUp.apply(this, args));
    }
};

// Show/Hide forms based on radio button selection
    $('input[name="screen_type"]').bind('change',function(){
        var showWelcome = ($(this).val() == 1);
        $('.welcome_screen').slideToggleOption(showWelcome);
        $('.training_screen').slideToggleOption(!showWelcome);
 });​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lqeqe/